# Event is null after Automapper Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, automapper

I have two main objects, DTO.Object1 and My.Object2. Both object have child object collection.

```
public class Object1
{
    public List<ChildObject1> ChildObjectList{get;set;}
}

public class Object2
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChildObject2> ChildObjectList{get;set;}
}
```

Before I map, I added one event to Object2> ChildObjectList

```
foreach(ChildObject2 co2 in ChildObjectList)
{
    co2.PropertyChange += MyPropertyChange;
}
```

Then I map these two object

```
__mapper.Map(DTO.Object1, My.Object2);
```

after that, that PropertyChange event from each `ChildObject2` is null.

This is how I CreateMap=>

```
public class ObjectMappingProfile: Profile
    {
        public MyMappingProfile()
        {
            this.CreateMap<Dto.Object1, Model.Object2>()
                    .EqualityComparison((dto, o) =>
                        dto.id== o.id);
        }
}
```

I also add `AddCollectionMappers();` at MapperConfiguration.

```
var autoMapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(x =>
            {
                x.AddCollectionMappers();
                x.AddProfile(typeof(ObjectMappingProfile));
});
```

Any Idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can you also include ChildObject1 and ChildObject2 classes?

Comment: @tontonsevilla, I can map property but the only event is null after map.I doubt its created new object when map. But I did the same way with other ppl does. don't know why it still not working.

Comment: @Loran, i've put together a Fiddle for running your scenario. However, I can't reproduce the scenario you've described. Can you have a look at it, and see what if different from your code? We could collaborate if you want, just send me a chat message.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uvo1Kd

Comment: @ThomasLuijken, Thank u so much, I will check and back to u soon.

Comment: @ThomasLuijken, I checked your sample. I did the same code with u. but I see my child object list was initializing when map parent. Under what kind of saturation it can initialize? I check the before-map value of the child object and its already change to initialize the object. Sorry for asking nonsense.

Comment: What versions of the nuget packages are you using? Just go make sure we're on the same version.

Comment: @ThomasLuijken, I did the same version with u.if I map eg.`Mapper.Map(DtoList[0],MList[0])`, it can map. But I don't know why if I map with collection It goes constructor of child object and initializes. Thank u.

Comment: @ThomasLuijken, If I change both to same type like List,List its can map. but can't with List,ObserableCollection.

Comment: Hmm, this is odd, since the fiddle also uses an observable collection for the destination. Any chance your can share a reproducible example?