# Map only if destination value is null

Tags: c#, automapper

I am new at automapper, I am trying to Map only if destination value is null, I checked the documentation but its only show condition for source value. May I know how to check destination value at condition?

```
this.CreateMap<DtoObject, MyObject>()
                .EqualityComparison((dto, o) =>
                    dto.id== o.id)
                    .ForMember(s => s.MyField, opt =>
                    {
                    
//I want to Map only MyField of destination object is null, otherwise I don't want to map. But How can I get destination's MyField value?
                   
        });
```

Comment: My rule is to only use AutoMapper in that case, if it does the mapping automatically. If you need complex mapping settings, it is easier to write a method that does this without Automaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve this effect.

The preferred method is to use the [Automapper conditional Mapping](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html):

```
        CreateMap<DtoObject, MyObject>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.MyField, opt =>
            {
                opt.PreCondition((source, dest, ctx) => dest.MyField == null);
                opt.MapFrom(src => src.MyField);
            });
```

Another method is by using the `AfterMap` method in combination with the `Ignore` during the mapping process, like this.

```
        CreateMap<DtoObject, MyObject>()
            .ForMember(d => d.MyField, a => a.Ignore())
            .AfterMap((source, destination) =>
            {
                if (destination.MyField == null)
                {
                    destination.Name = source.MyField;
                }
            });
```

This will tell AutoMapper to ignore the property during the mapping process, and execute some custom logic during the after map.

Comment: Thanks Its very helpful. Can u help me also this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63405900/event-is-null-after-automapper-collection?noredirect=1#comment112119160_63405900

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [AutoMapper Conditional mapping](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html).

Using `PreCondition` allows to access `source` and `destination` and set condition when the property should be mapped:

```
this.CreateMap<DtoObject, MyObject>()
            .EqualityComparison((dto, o) =>
                dto.id== o.id)
                .ForMember(s => s.MyField, opt =>
                {
                    opt.PreCondition((dest, src) => dest.SomeDestinationProperty == null);
                    opt.MapFrom(src => src.SomeSourceProperty);
                });
```